# Is it safe to uninstall MySQL Connector if I'm using it as a reference (Visual C#)?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I'm in the process of developing an application that interacts with a MySQL database. Because it interacts with some older software, it has to be built in .NET 3.5.

Another application I'm developing was made from scratch and doesn't talk to anything other than MySQL. Therefore I built it with .NET 4.5.

I have the latest version of the MySQL connector installed on my developing machine to work with .NET 4.5, but 3.5 doesn't like it because the connector requires 4.5.

Here are my questions:

- Is it safe to uninstall the newer MySQL connector, since the reference DLL's have already been copied to that project, without breaking my 4.5 project?
- Is it a better idea to just run both off of the older connector version?

I'd test this out myself but I'm in a position where I don't have admin rights. I have to bother IT anytime I want to do anything, and they generally like it if I know what I'm doing before I go talk to them.

Thanks all.

Comment: if you uninstall connector, application will work but you will lose EDMX designer and database first creation of EF. (supposing you are using entity framework). You also must have in mind where those application will be deployed. if are on same server, i will stick with the same connector. MySQL connector isn't great software so don't expect to work 'fine'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon the same issue:

- You can run both applications off of the old framework, even if one is built with .NET 4.5 it can handle the old MySQL connector framework. I have yet to experience any issues with version compatibility between the .NET 4.5 project and the connector built for 3.5.
- You will have to make a new reference to the older framework, however - once the new MySQL connector is uninstalled your applications that rely on it will cease to function until you install another version and reference that one.